# Outer measure of $\mathbb R^*$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I know outer measure of $\mathbb R$ is $\infty$ But what about outer measure of $\mathbb R^*$ is also $\infty$ ?

My answer:

$\mathbb R^*=\mathbb R$\ {$0$}$ =(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$

$m^*(\mathbb R^*) \leq m^*((-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty))$

$= \infty + \infty = \infty$

True ?

Comment: This just shows the upper bound, which is trivial.

Comment: The answer will depend on how you define the outer measure.

Comment: Is not the outer measure for any interval is his length ?

Comment: normally it's defined to be some infimum of sums of lengths of covers, right?

Comment: Yes right, but how can i find outer measure of $\mathbb R^*$ by countable covers ?

Comment: http://planetmath.org/proofthattheouterlebesguemeasureofanintervalisitslength

Comment: And once you know this for finite intervals, $n = m^\ast((0,n)) \le m^\ast(\mathbb{R}^\ast)$ for all $n$ so it cannot be finite, so must be $+\infty$.